# Upload a CSV File and Show it as JSON Encoded Format in PHP

Tags: php, csv, json

`{"id":"1","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"}` This is my JSON Format. I want to upload a CSV File. From which the JSON format will be shown. The CSV File format will be like below: i am using mongo db

```
Id  FirstName LastName
1  john      doe
2  doe       john
```

Comment: Read csv & create an array then echo json_encode($newArray);

Comment: Do you want to parse a csv file and display as json? may be fgetcsv can help http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: "1""john""2""doe" i am getting in this format, my needed format is {"id":"1","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"} this. i am using mongo db

Comment: Any one know the answer? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($json_string, TRUE)` for convert json string to array

Then create a CSV file

`Example`

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');



$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```